# ansible mingw32-make out of memory

Tags: out-of-memory, ansible, mingw32

I try to **automate a build via ansible on window7 Virtual Machine**.
My build is base on cmake (version 3.7.1)  and mingw32 (version 4.9.2) as compiler.
If I do the **build directly in the VM** by enter manually all command in the powershell, **everything work find**.

```
git clone --recursive somedepot
cd somedepot
cmake.bat .
mingw32-make all
```

**Note :** cmake.bat is the following script :

```
@cmake.exe -G"MinGW Makefile" %*
```

But when I try to **do the same by ansible** I got **"cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 176080 bytes\r\nmingw32-make[2]"** at the execution of **mingw32-make all**. But not on all build failed, I test my script before in a **simple build** and **work well**. It's when I wanted to go to the "real build" (which is more **bigger**) that the **problem append**.

Here my playbook :

```
- name: Some Build
  hosts: win_build

  tasks :
    - name: Get src
      win_command: git clone --recursive --branch "{{ tag_src }}" "{{ url_src }}" "{{ path_cmake }}"

    - name: CMake
      win_command: cmake.bat .
      args:
        chdir: "{{ path_cmake }}"

    - name: Make
      win_command: mingw32-make all                        
      args:
        chdir: "{{ path_cmake }}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was a bug in powershell3. I applied [microsoft hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2842230/-out-of-memory-error-on-a-computer-that-has-a-customized-maxmemorypershellmb-quota-set-and-has-wmf-3.0-installed) and everything work fine.